# Differentials where the variable undergoes a percentage increase. Where am I wrong?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $R = \frac{k}{r^4}$, where $k$ is some constant.  Find the change in $R$ as $r$ is increased by 10%.  $R$ is the resistance of blood flow, $r$ is the radius of a vein.

This problem seems easy enough to do with some simple algebra, but I'm lead to believe (based on context) that this problem should be attempted using differentials.  However, when I attempt the problem using differentials I get a completely different answer.

**Method 1:**  $R_0 = \frac{k}{r_0^4}$ (our original resistance). $R=\frac{k}{r^4}$ (our new resistance). Let $r=1.1r_0$. Then $\frac{R}{R_0} = \frac{k/r^4}{k/r_0^4}=\frac{r_0}{r}=\frac{1}{1.1^4} \approx .683$.  This tells us that an increase by 10 percent in our radius results in a $31.7$% decrease in $R$.  This is what I would wager is the correct answer.

**Method 2:**  $\frac{dR}{dr} = \frac{-4k}{r^5}$  Thus, $dR=\frac{-4k}{r^5}*dr$.  Now, usually I'm given some fact like, $r$ goes from 3 to 2.98 or something like that, where $\Delta r$ is explicit.  In this case though, our $\Delta r = .1r$.  $$\Delta R \approx \frac{-4k}{r^5}*\Delta r=-.4\frac{k}{r^4}=-.4R$$  Here, we see that a 10% increase in the radius should give rise to a 40% decrease in $R$, contradicting our past solution.

**Question:**  Where am I going wrong?  I feel like my algebraic method should be exactly correct, but this contradicts my differential method.  In the second method, I can see that as $r$ gets larger and larger, our approximation should get worse and worse.  Does this have something to do with my contradictory answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your methods are correct. The first one gives you the exact decrease in R, while the second is just a first order approximation which becomes better when your change in $r$ is smaller.

Comment: Yes, as long as a derivative exists, or at least one-sided derivative. For example $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but the one sided derivatives exist and they are -1 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are astonished because your two results have a different sign. Well, this is because your **Method 1**, is not correct.

The: *change in $R$  as $r$ is increased by $10$%* is:
$$
\Delta R = R-R_0=\dfrac{k}{(1.1 r_0)^4}-\dfrac{k}{ r_0^4}=k\left( \dfrac{1-(1.1)^4}{(1.1)^4r_0^4}\right)
$$
and this change relative to $R_0$ is:
$$
\dfrac{\Delta R}{R_0}=\dfrac{1}{(1.1)^4}-1 \approx-0.32 < 0
$$

Your **Method 2** is correct but, as noted in the answer of Svetoslav, it is a linear approximation so, for a variation of $0.1$ in the independent variable it gives a result that is different from the exact value because the function is not linear.

Comment: Why would you say my method 1 is incorrect?  It gives exactly the same answer as you have given.  Namely, they both show a 32% **decrease** in $R$.  Moreover, the two results don't give different signs.  They both show that $R$ decreases as $r$ increases.  What astonishes me is the degree to which they are different from one another.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was going to say- the first method of @PaddlingGhost is correct, because his sign is in the text - he wrote 31.7 % decrease.

Comment: Sorry! I did not notice the world "decrease" . So my answer is a confirm of the answer of Svetoslav.